# document.write почему выполняется только первая строка?

Tags: javascript

Если закомментировать первую, то выполняется только вторая. Если вторую и первую, то только тогда выполняется третья document.write.

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Object Oriented Javascript</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                
                function SecretCode(){
                    var secretNum = 78;
                    
                    this.guessNum = function(num){
                        if(num > 78){
                            return "Lower";
                        }else if(num < 78){
                            return "Higher";
                        }else{
                            return "You guessed it";
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                var secret = new SecretCode();
                
                document.write("Value of secretNum " + secret.secretNum + "<br /");
                
                document.write("Is 70 the number " + secret.guessNum(70) + "<br /");
                
                SecretCode.prototype.getSecret = function(){
                    return this.secretNum;
                }
                
                document.write("The secret number is  " + secret.getSecret() + "<br /");
                
            </script>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: закройте тэг: `... + "<br />"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, что пишется после первого незакрытого `<br /`

```
document.write("Value of secretNum " + secret.secretNum + "<br /");
```

оказывается внутри этого тэга - его атрибутами, и снаружи не видно.

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Object Oriented Javascript</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                
                function SecretCode(){
                    this.secretNum = 78;
                    
                    this.guessNum = function(num){
                        if(num > 78){
                            return "Lower";
                        }else if(num < 78){
                            return "Higher";
                        }else{
                            return "You guessed it";
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                var secret = new SecretCode();
                
                document.write("Value of secretNum " + secret.secretNum + "<br />");
                
                document.write("Is 70 the number " + secret.guessNum(70) + "<br />");
                
                SecretCode.prototype.getSecret = function(){
                    return this.secretNum;
                }
                
                document.write("The secret number is  " + secret.getSecret() + "<br />");
                
            </script>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: После двух лет изучения Java я пришел к необходимости изучения javascript. Я не ошибся?)))

Comment: @НиколайБеляков Конечно нет. У Вас впереди немало веселых минут ).